# I want to get the sum of count of each unique entry from a particular column from google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a google spread sheet,I want to get the sum of count of each unique entry from a particular column('Text' in this example).However the entries in the column themselves repeat.

Eg:

```
    Text Count
    a    3 
    b    4
    a    8
    abd  4
    c    1
    t    2
    abd  5
    a    2
    v    1
    v    67
    w    44
```

I want the output as:

```
    Text Count
    a    13 
    b    4
    abd  9
    c    1
    t    2
    v    68
    w    44
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that you want to get the results in the text column automatically, use a Pivot table in Excel:

- Mark your data including the column captions "Text" and "Count"
- Go to the "Insert" tab in the ribbon, hit the arrow below and choose "PivotChart and PivotTable"
- The cells for the raw data should already be entered. In the lower part of the window choose where you want to get the Pivot table. Then hit Ok.
- There should be an area on the right-hand side of the window where you can choose which data you want to evaluate. Choose Text and Count.
- There should already be the sum of the Count values. If you want to get a different quantity such as the average, hit "Sum of Count" with the right mouse button and

Comment: Please check this document: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en. I thought a solution for Excel might also help you because you have added the Excel tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks...will look into.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `GROUP BY` and a `SUM`:

```
SELECT text, sum(count) as count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY text
```